# regex split text with delimiter but don't split when the delimiter is in between ()

Tags: java, regex, scala, split

I wanted to split a text in Scala with `,` delimiter but don't split when the `,` is in parentheses but extract the `,` and ignore the parentheses, for example to split the following:

`one, two (,) three`

I should get an array containing:

```
`one`
`two , three`
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are there `(` and `)` immediately before and after `,` or can the input be: `one, two (foo   , bar) three` also?

Comment: @anubhava, the `(` and `)` are immediately before and after `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?![^)()]*\)),|\((?=,)|(?<=,)\)
```

You can try this. See demo: http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/2

You will have to join the last three contents of list to get the second match.

Comment: this work except when used in a split function it will split the `two (,) three` to `two`, `,` and `three`. But I wanted if this `(?![^)()]*\))` takes care of removing the `()`. Can you please explain how your solution works? Thank you

Comment: @mnish that is why i wrote you will need to join last three to get correctm match.It splits by `,` which is not between `()`.Or it splits by `(` which is followed by `,`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
(?<!\)), *(?!\))
```

In Java:

```
(?<!\\)), *(?!\\))
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xR1dT6/2)

#### [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/wYyHCC)

It will break example input into:

- `one`
- `two (,) three`

Comment: thank you but this will split the example string to `one' and `two(,)three`